# Find subfield of R? Other than Q.

Tags: real-analysis

Question: If in the field axioms for $\mathbb{R}$ we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by any other set with two operations $+$ and $\cdot$ that satisfy these nine
properties, then we say that that structure is a field. For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field. The rules are valid since
$\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}$. The only thing that needs to be checked is that $a + b$ and $a \cdot b$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$ if both $a$ and $b$ are. For this
reason $\mathbb{Q}$ is called a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$. Find another subfield.

I think the question is asking for a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ other than $\mathbb{Q}$. But, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ don't have multiplicative inverse in them. It didn't satisfy all nine properties for addation and multipcation. so I want to ask what is the subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, other than $\mathbb{Q}$?

Can I use $\mathbb{C}$? Because it have some part is in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$. $\;$

Comment: See [algebraic reals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) and [periods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods).

Answer (score 7):

No, $\mathbb{C}$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ since it's not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. There are some non-trivial subfields of $\mathbb{R}$, though; as a simple example,

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2) = \{a + b \sqrt 2 : a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$
is a field under the usual operations, and is not all of $\mathbb{R}$. The only tricky part of proving this is to check closure under inverses, which follows from the fact that

$$\frac{1}{a + b \sqrt 2} = \frac{a - b \sqrt 2}{a^2 - 2b^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\Bbb C\not\subseteq\Bbb R,$ it is not a subfield of $\Bbb R.$

Instead, consider something like this:

$$\{a+b\sqrt2:a,b\in\Bbb Q\}$$ You can show this to be a field (with the usual operations), and contained (strictly) in $\Bbb R.$ (For multiplicative inverses, the trick is to rationalize the denominator.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the set $\{a+b\sqrt{3}:a,b\in{\Bbb{Q}}\}$ is another field.